# Construction of the base class constructor class assignment

Tags: c#, class, instance

```
public class Test1
{
    public int Q1 { get; set; }
    public string Q2 { get; set; }

}

public class Test2 : Test1
{
    public Test2(Test1 Value)
    {
        Q1 = Value.Q1;
        Q2 = Value.Q2;
        //Does this way of writing is getting very long and difficult

    }
}

public class Test2 : Test1
{
    public Test2(Test1 Value)
    {
        base = Value;
        //In this way a short and easy ways
    }
}



   public Test1 ExampleTest()
    {
        return new Test1();
    }

    public void Example()
    {
        Test2 t = new Test2();

        t = ExampleTest();
    }
```

I direct assignment to the class inheritance How do I get?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I suggest you read a book about C# or OOP in general.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is not bad, but the way you're attempting is little smelly. For instance `List<T>` class has something similar like `class List<T> : IEnumerable<T> { public List<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) { } }`. But in your case you have a base class (instead of interface) which makes the whole equation different. There can be many ways to go about this, but in this one case you should think of composition first. Wouldn't this do: `public class Test2
{
    Test1 Test1;
    public Test2(Test1 Value)
    {
        Test1 = Value
    }
}`.

Comment: get a quick assignment to the class inheritance can not I?

class inheritance I received a small sample here, but how do I do it the easiest assignment or a sample could not find a relevant source.

Answer (score 1):

Both are wrong -

In 1st you are initializing base class members in the derived class constructor and is a bad practice. The issue here is you must make use of inheritence here and let base class initializes the inherited members through base class constructor.

In 2nd , you are first creating the base class object and then passing it for creation of derived objet. Its a wastage of memory as we don't need base class object for instantiating derived object. Moreover this approach will not work in case of abstract classes.

Comment: *In 2nd, you missed main point* `base = Value` is not at all valid won't work even if it is concrete class.

Comment: I believe he just wrote that pseudo code. He might meant mapping the values of passed Test 1 object to inherited members in Test 2.

Comment: Nope, that's what he does in version1 then why pseudo code again for the same thing? I suspect OP did it intentionally.